# Screen Orientation changes my running activity

Tags: android, screen, screen-orientation

I have an app in which when I press a `Button`, another screen is showed. I have added the classes for other screen, and also edited the manifest file and my problem is this: When I am on the other screen (not my initial one) and I turn me mobile screen (change the orientation) my app goes to the main screen, just like I have pressed the back button (or just like pressing the Home button that there is on my screen2). If you need any code, tell me and I will edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best, but maybe the easiest solution is to add

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

to every activity in your manifest so it looks like

```
<activity android:name="com.your.activity"
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

Comment: By far not the best, this is a bad way to handle this. You should allow your app to run `onCreate` when the device goes through a config change, and handle the state using the `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: As I sad ... not the best solution. But definitely sufficient for a lot of cases - and maybe for this one, too.

Comment: @ blindstuff: because its my first app, can you make it more clear. If I edit the code can you help me more?

Answer (score 4):

Looks that you have messed with Activity stack. Keep in mind that every time you change orientation of your app the onCreate method is fired.

And of course your code is essential.